# No static files on static page in django

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-staticfiles

I have a static website in django at: domain.com/press/. The page at this address is visible, but there is a problem with static files - they don't appear.

Error in console (F12):

```
domain.com/press/%7B%%20static%20'images/presslogo.png'%20%%7D Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

My settings in nginx:

```
location /press/ {
    alias /path_to_templates/;
    index press.html;
}
```

Part of my html code:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Press</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="{% static 'images/presslogo.png' %}">
</body>
</html>
```

setting.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

How can I display an image on a static page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/press/` is being served by nginx. Hence `<img src="{% static 'images/presslogo.png' %}">` will not work.

Please give exact path of your image. That is

```
<img src="domain.com/<your-static-url>/images/presslogo.png">
```

Comment: This isn't the correct answer. The correct answer is to set `STATIC_URL` appropriately.

Comment: @DanielRoseman He is serving /press/ via nginx. Which means STATIC_URL or any feature related to django will not work.

Comment: In order to use STATIC_URL. /press/ needs to served via django

Comment: No, that is simply completely untrue. STATIC_URL is just a variable that points to wherever your static files are being served from. It doesn't matter if they're via nginx, or S3, or what; they just need a URL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I disagree with you. Can you point me to any such working example?

Comment: Well, you're free to disagree. But I can't understand why you think this. STATIC_URL is just a URL, I can't imagine why you think it wouldn't work. I only have to point to the actual docs on deploying static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: @DanielRoseman, What are I understood from above question @user9192656 don't want /press/ getting served by django. That is the reason he has put ngnix location config. As nginx not aware of django specific thing it will not work. Just check console error in a question. `static`  is not getting resolved to exact path instead it is treating whole template code as html code

Comment: Stop saying it won't work. **It's just a URL**. Django doesn't care *where* the URL points to, it's just a string. This question is not about Django *serving* the files, it's just about *pointing* to them. You are simply wrong.